# Azure Bot transcripts not being saved

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-blob-storage, bot-framework-composer

I have a bot developed in Bot Framework Composer and have implemented Blob transcript storage. Transcript storage works when I run the bot locally. But once I publish the bot to azure, no transcripts are saved.

I presume there is some error in the azure bot accessing the blob storage but I don't see any errors generated in azure. The blob storage does not show any access attempts indicating to me that the request never gets to blob storage.

I updated CORS on the blob storage to allow all origins and methods but this did not have any effect.

Any suggestions what to look for or what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there are two steps to adding transcripts to an existing bot.

In Composer, settings:

1. Add the blob storage settings in the runtimeSettings > components > features section:

```
      "blobTranscript": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=bottranscripts;AccountKey=<your key here>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
        "containerName": "transcripts"
      }
```

At this point, running the bot locally should store transcripts in blob storage in Azure.

2. Again, in Composer, check the publish settings for publishing to Azure. There should be a setting

```
    "blobStorage": {
      "connectionString": "<ConnectionString>",
      "container": "transcripts",
      "name": "<myBotName>"
    }
```

Make sure that the connection string matches what you entered in the runtimeSettings section. The bot in Azure will use the publish settings, not the runtimeSettings for transcripts.